# Getting multiple cell ids for triangulation - c# windows mobile

Tags: c#, location, windows-mobile, ril

I've been trying to get CellIDs for multiple cellular towers to triangulate the position of a windows mobile phone in a C# application.

I am able to get the lat/long of the currently connected cell tower using David Tiger's WMLocationInfo dll from http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=934948, but this is not accurate enough because it uses only the current cell tower. I need an accuracy of ~100M or so without using GPS. So if I can get the CellIDs and signal strengths of at least three towers, I'll should be able to improve the accuracy to a reasonable extent.

I found a discussion at [Get Multiple Cell IDs for location using Cellular Towers C# Windows Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19387531/get-multiple-cell-ids-for-location-using-cellular-towers-c-sharp-windows-mobile) where johansebasb was addressing the same requirement.

Can someone point me towards a sample project or code that I can use for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at [How to properly triangulate gsm cell towers to get a location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329877/how-to-properly-triangulate-gsm-cell-towers-to-get-a-location)?

Comment: Thanks, Paul. Yes, I looked at that, but I'm not sure if the devices I'm targeting will support the AT+KCELL command, and rather than experiment with that I thought the easier solution would be to manually find 3 neighboring towers with CellIDs, get the signal strength and write an algorithm to calculate the approximate position.

Comment: @PaulH Incidentally, I haven't been able to find out how to execute an AT command in a windows mobile application. The dozens of examples I could find all showed how to pass an AT command to a GSM modem or device attached to a PC through serial or USB. Is there some code you could point me towards?

Comment: The answer posted by @Jared Kells shows the math your application needs. The API you want to get the cell tower ID is the RIL. Specifically [RIL_GetCellTowerInfo()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa923065.aspx)

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19387531/get-multiple-cell-ids-for-location-using-cellular-towers-c-sharp-windows-mobile

Comment: Thanks, @PaulH! I appreciate your taking the time to respond and find the links. Yes, I did implement the solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19387531/get-multiple-cell-ids-for-location-using-cellular-towers-c-sharp-windows-mobile , but unfortunately the search for multiple towers takes far too long - sometimes over half-an-hour to find two cell towers, and I haven't been able to successfully find a third tower.

Comment: I even tried passing an AT command inside a windows mobile application trying COM0 to COM9 unsuccessfully. If the port number is > 9 I get a message saying the portname is invalid and for single-digit port numbers the response is either junk or 'Port COMx does not exist' . Is it even possible to execute an AT command from a mobile device application? If so, AT+KCELL may return all visible towers, and I can take it from there. Once again, I appreciate your help.

Comment: I have never done it myself, but you may be able to use the TAPI to send AT commands. Try using [lineGetId on a comm/datamodem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734853(VS.85).aspx) and see if you can WriteFile("AT") to it. I think there is a c# wrapper for TAPI on [opennetcf](http://tapi.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1):

There are two probs with that:

1. The RIL does not expose that function
2. You may send AT^moni command to GSM modem but this may disturb or corrupt the RIL. The RIL is sending and parsing all commands to control the modem. Think of the RIL being the wrapper around all modem communication.
3. You need a comm port to send (inject) AT commands to the modem. That may be implemented or not by the RIL driver.
4. If the modem does not support AT^moni you are lost. The Siemens MC75 supports cell monitoring via:

AT^SMONC Cell Monitoring
The AT^SMONC execute command delivers cell information containing 9 values from a maximum of 7 base stations. The first base station is the serving cell.

AFAIK Sierra Modems do support AT^moni too. Qualcomm? Don't know.

Comment: Sorry for not responding earlier - was out of the country and out of contact. Thank you @PaulH and josef for your responses and help with this, but it looks as if I have to put this on ice for the moment. There seems to be no straightforward answer to this problem.